# How to ping my qemu virtual raspberry guest

Tags: networking, qemu

I configured as root, my network on my laptop for get a bridge like this :

```
ip tuntap add dev tap0 mode tap group $USER
ip link set dev tap0 up promisc on
ip addr add 0.0.0.0 dev tap0
ip link add br0 type bridge
ip link set br0 up
ip link set tap0 master br0
echo "0" |  tee --append /sys/class/net/br0/bridge/stp_state
ip addr add 192.168.2.1/24 dev br0
sysctl net.ipv4.conf.tap0.proxy_arp=1
sysctl net.ipv4.conf.enp2s0.proxy_arp=1
sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o enp2s0 -j MASQUERADE
iptables -A FORWARD -i br0 -o enp2s0 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i enp2s0 -o br0 -j ACCEPT
```

I started my QEMU ARM cpu like this :

```
qemu-system-arm -cpu arm1176 -m 256 \
-M versatilepb -no-reboot -serial stdio \
-append "root=/dev/sda2 panic=1 rootfstype=ext4 rw" \
-kernel kernel-qemu-4.4.12-jessie \
-hda 2016-05-27-raspbian-jessie-lite.img \
-net nic -net tap,ifname=tap0,script=no,downscript=no
```

I put `192.168.2.2` as static  ip address in my Raspberry emulation. The emulation  is able to ping the address of enp2s0, br0 and/or world wide web. But I'm not able to ping it from my laptop.

What did I miss ?

Answer (score 0):

OK I finally found the issue :

```
iptables -A FORWARD -i tap0 -o br0 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i br0 -o tap0 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

The root cause is the route has been open between `enp2s0` and `br0` but not between `br0` and `tap0`. After this booth command I was able to do a `ssh` connexion to my QEMU.
easy if you understood